# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'. Error when trying to get data from Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am trying to retrieve data from a document stored in Firestore. I've tried several times to find a way to fix this error but haven't been able to find something useful.

Here's my code.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GetUserName extends StatelessWidget {
  final String documentId;

  GetUserName(this.documentId);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Drivers');

    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
          return Text("Document does not exist");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Object? data = snapshot.data!.data();
          return Text(data!['username']);
        }

        return Text("loading");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The error happens when I try to retrieve 'username' from data.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you paste the output of `snapshot.data!.data()` via print?

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies in the difference between `Object` and `dynamic`.

In Dart, `Object?` is the "top type", which essentially means: "all values are `Object?`s".

`dynamic` is often used in a similar situation (when you don't know the type of the data you're working with, and don't want the type system complaining at you), but it has a very different meaning. In short, it means "turn off type checking because I know what I'm doing".

The main difference between `Object?` and `dynamic` comes down to their members.

`Object?` has a few members defined on it:

- `toString()`
- `runtimeType`
- `hashCode`
- `noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation)`

All objects share these members, because all objects are `Object?`s.
If you have a value of static type `Object?`, these are the only 4 members that Dart can guarantee exist, so these are the only ones you are allowed to call (just like you'll get an error if you try to call `"some string".notARealMethod()`).

`dynamic` does the opposite: it assumes all possible members exist and never gives you a warning for any access, so for example:

```
String s = "hello";
s.notARealMethod();  // compile time error
final d = s as dynamic;  // explicitly cast to dynamic
d.notARealMethod();  // now throws at runtime
```

So, going back to your code, you have this:

```
Object? data = snapshot.data!.data();
return Text(data!['username']);
```

`data` is an `Object?`, so `data!` is an `Object`, and as we saw before, the only 4 members on `Object` are: `toString()`, `runtimeType`, `hashCode` and `noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation)`. So Dart will complain because it can't guarantee that `[]` exists.

To fix this:

1. use `dynamic` instead of `Object?`. It won't give you a compile error, but it will throw at runtime if the value ends up not having the `[]` operator (although because this is coming from firestore, this is a safe bet)
2. use a type check (and make use of type promotion):

```
Object? data = snapshot.data;
if (data is Map<String, dynamic>) {
  // dart now knows that data is a Map, and now you can safely call Map methods (e.g. [])
  return Text(data['username']);
}

throw "not a map";  
// or 
return SomeErrorWidget();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain this to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
snapshot.data()['username'] => snapshot['username']
```